# How to get DOMElement in DOM Event Listener in DotNetBrowser?

Tags: dotnetbrowser

With reference to http://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/documentation/dom-events, I need to add an event listener for the whole document, listening for click events. In the event listener I need to get the DOMElement where the user clicked. Is this possible. Could not find from documentation/samples how to get this from DOMEventArgs.

Thank you !

Edit: I guess DOMEventArgs.Target can be simply cast to DOMElement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your guess is correct. `DOMEventArgs.Target` and `DOMEventArgs.CurrentTarget` can be cast to `DOMElement` in general case.

Comment: If you follow the documentation, this retrieves not the selected element on the page, but the page as a whole... since the e.CurrentTarget == document.DocumentElement of the entire page.